# React Sorting Issue when using UseState: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React, I'm still a beginner and I'm encountering an issue while attempting to sort an array of objects in a React component. The error message I'm receiving is "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price'). This happen only when I use UseState, I tried not to use it and use the sorting's comparison function directly   `let productsPrice = productData.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price))` and it worked very well.

**Code:**

```
import '../style/products.css';
import productData from '../products-data';
import Product from './Product';
import { useState } from 'react';

function ProductsList() {
  const compareAscendingPrice = (a, b) => a.price - b.price;
  const compareAscendingRate = (a, b) => a.rating.rate - b.rating.rate;
  const compareAscendingAlpha = (a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title, 'en');

  // let type = compareAscendingAlpha;
  let [type, SetType] = useState(compareAscendingPrice); // useState hook
  let productsPrice = productData.sort(type);
  let products = [...productsPrice].map((item) => {
    return <Product item={item} key={item.id} />;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div className="products__filter">
        <div className="products__filter__search">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
        <div className="products__filter__sort">
          <label htmlFor="sort">Sort by:</label>
          <select
            name="sort"
            id="sort"
            onChange={(e) => {
              if (e.target.value === 'price') {
                SetType(compareAscendingPrice);
              } else if (e.target.value === 'rating') {
                SetType(compareAscendingRate);
              } else if (e.target.value === 'title') {
                SetType(compareAscendingAlpha);
              }
            }}
          >
            <option value="price">Price</option>
            <option value="rating">Rating</option>
            <option value="title">Title</option>
          </select>
          <div className="products__filter__direction">
            <label htmlFor="ascending">Ascending</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ascending" id="ascending" />
            <label htmlFor="descending">Descending</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="descending" id="descending" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="products">{products}</div>;
    </>
  );
}

export default ProductsList;
```

What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the price property is properly recognized during sorting?

I checked the data files, I looked on the internet, but I did not find any solution.

Note: I'm learning React I'm still a beginner.

Comment: which line gives that error? the one with the useState call or the one with the sort call?...by the way SetType should be lower case S (setType)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems there (well, really two different versions of the same problem): Both `useState` itself and the state setter you get from it expect that when you pass a function into them, they're supposed to *call* that function rather than store it. For `useState` itself, it expects to call that function only during the initial mount ([docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#avoiding-recreating-the-initial-state)). For the state setter, it expects that you want to queue a state update callback ([docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)). You can't directly store functions in state.

You have at least a couple of alternatives:

1. Store a flag that you'll then use to pass to a generalized sort function that knows which of those sort functions to call.

   or
2. Store an object with the desired sort callback as a property.

Here's an example of #1:

```
const comparisons = {
    price: (a, b) => a.price - b.price,
    rating: (a, b) => a.rating.rate - b.rating.rate,
    value: (a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title, 'en'),
};

function ProductsList() {
    // ...
    const [sortType, setSortType] = useState("price");
    let productsPrice = productData.sort(comparisons[type]);
    // ...
```

Then when setting it:

```
<select
name="sort"
id="sort"
    onChange={(e) => {
      setSortType(e.target.value);
    }}
>
```

There I've used `e.target.value` directly by making the option values the keys of the `comparisons` object, but you could continue to use a `switch` if you preferred.

*(I changed `type` to `sortType` to be more specific, and used an initial lower-case letter because by convention, functions with upper-case initial letters are constructor functions.)*

Answer (score -1):

You haven't defined price in compareAscendingPrice arrow function. That's the issue. First of all, you have to get the data from array!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).